# Prevent aws s3 sync from creating empty folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the [aws s3 sync command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) to copy directories from an s3 bucket to my EC2 instance. For instance:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/folder-1 ~/folder-1
```

Some of the folders I try to sync are not on the s3 bucket yet. So when executing the above command, `my-bucket/folder-1` won't be found on s3.
In this case, I don't want the local folder `~/folder-1` to be created if it does not exist yet. But it is !

Is there a way to prevent the command from creating the local folder ?

One possible solution is to check if the folder exist before executing the sync command, with the [head-object command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/head-object.html). But this force me to execute 2 commands instead of one, which is not ideal considering I want to sync hundreds of folders every day.

Comment: I don't see any option with `aws s3 sync` to prevent this. You might raise an issue at the GitHub repo because you can make a good argument that sync should not create this folder if there are no objects with that prefix. PS HeadObject of the folder prefix would not be the correct test to do in advance.

Comment: Remember that S3 is an object store.  There are not folders per se but rather part of the overall key to the object.  I could see a new command line option or I could see just running `find . -type d -empty -delete` after you're done.  The find command makes more sense to me as you just don't want empty directories on your file system - it sounds like they are ok in S3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the aws s3 sync command does not provide an option to prevent the creation of the local directory if the source directory does not exist in the S3 bucket.

As you mentioned, one workaround is to use the `aws s3api head-object` or `aws s3 ls` command to check if the directory exists in the S3 bucket before running the aws `s3 sync` command.

Another option is to write a script that wraps the `aws s3 sync` command and only runs it if the source directory exists in the S3 bucket. Here's an example in bash:

```bash
bucket="my-bucket"
folder="folder-1"

if aws s3 ls "s3://$bucket/$folder/" > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    aws s3 sync "s3://$bucket/$folder" "~/folder-1"
else
    echo "Directory s3://$bucket/$folder does not exist."
fi
```